# Something like "select" from "where" with Handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

Using [handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com) as a template engine I need to query a `json` file and from here loop through an *array* within an *object* in said file. The flow is intended to work like: **If** a value define via `data-attribute` on *click* matches a *string* within an *object array* then loop and show data based on those conditions.

Essentially I need a query it like I would back-end to a database,(Using Laravel) e.g:

```
$attr = "Red";
$prodcuts = DB::table('products')->Where('tags', $tag)->get();
```

---

I am working from a very large `json` file for this. For example sake I created a much smaller one if you need it reference sake:

https://gist.github.com/Panoply/15dc30a9fc598d07b24f0f13a5d42df4

I am aware that with *handlebars.js* I need to create a helper to make a string with a value:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("ifValue", function(conditional, options) {
  if (conditional !== options.hash.equals) {
    return options.fn(this);
  } else {
    return options.inverse(this);
  }
});
```

Then I would have my handlebars loop:

```
<ul>
{{#each products}}
{{#ifvalue tags equals='Blue'}}

<li>{{title}}</li>
<li>{{handle}}</li>
<li>{{tags}}</li>
{{#with images.[0]}}<li>{{src}}</li>{{/with}}  
{{#with variants.[0]}}<li>{{price}}</li>{{/with}}

{{/ifvalue}}
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

Issue is I get a blank result. You can try these code block at http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/ – Considering that the tags are in an `object array` I might be having some conflict.

Comment: ifValue case sensitive? also try adding content in your {{else}} to test your conditional / inverse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Handlebars is touchy. If you stumble across this, here is how I fixed it:

Handlebars:

```
{{#products}}
{{#inArray tags "Red"}}
   {{title}}
 {{#with images.[0]}}<img src="{{ this.src }}">{{/with}} 
{{/inArray}}
{{/products}}
```

Helper (Create an inArray):

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('inArray', function(array, value, options) {
    if (array.indexOf.call(array, value) >= 0) {
      return options.fn(this);
    } else {
      return options.inverse(this);
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up, I actually needed to know this today.